# How can I set the clock to 24 hour mode?

Tags: 10.10, gdm, login-screen, time, clock

How can I set the clock to global (24h time) in Maverick instead of am/pm? Including the login screen?

I mean there's no option to do that in rclick clock > preferences or in system > admin > time & date.

Answer (score 11):

**The normal way :**

- Go to System -> Administration -> Language Support
- On the Text Tab, choose your prefered language to display numbers, dates, ...

**The advanced way for your Desktop Applet :**

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
- Type: gconf-editor & Hit return
- Navigate to “Apps > Panel > Applets > Clock_Screen0 > Prefs”
- Double-click on the ‘Format’ value. Change it to ‘24-hour'

**Login Screen**

There was an option in Ubuntu previous versions in the GDM setup GUI (System > Admin > Login Window) but not in maverick, bug is reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/445674)

Comment: You might wanna add the bug report(s): [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/445674) and [GNOME Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=626896).